# why is Linux Mint/Ubuntu killing my CPUs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, linux-mint

I'm windows user for many years, however, I would like to switch to a linux distro(Mint probably) that won't kill my CPU.

My problem is that no matter if I install(Mint or Ubuntu) it on hardware or in a virtual environment(VMWare) it will keep my CPU fans spinning about 99% of the time at max RPM, even when it's idle, tho' after some period of being idle, it will spin at lower RPM, as soon as I log back in, it goes at full speed ahead.

I haven't done any system changes(not that I'm aware) that could cause this issue, even after a clean install the issue persists.

My question is: Is there any way that I can fix this, could it be some issue regarding my hardware(it is only about 1.5 years old...)?

The latest installs are:

- Mint Lisa
- Ubuntu 10.04

Thank you!

Comment: It'll be a driver or VM software issue. Try installing it natively with a dual boot to get fully immersed into Linux.

Comment: @MattJoiner "My problem is that no matter if I install(Mint or Ubuntu) it on hardware or in a virtual environment"

Comment: @DavidStratton would you be so kind and point me where to ask this question?

Comment: I would say either superusers or linux_unix.se or askubuntu.se

Comment: On the StackExchange network, perhaps ServerFault.com.  Otherwise, the Linux and Unix site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/  More likely, however, would be in the Linux forums.

Comment: can any of you please migrate my question, I have no way of posting this on serverfault.com or unix.stackexchange.com, it thinks that I'm a bot... asks me to enter captcha but it doesn't show me an input box or anything, just a button "I'm a human being"...

Comment: Search for overheating problems, I've seen posts on ubuntu forums that may help you, it is usually a small cahnge to the grub file. I wish I had your problem, I'd rather replace a cheap fan than burn out the cpu from over heating.

Comment: @Rick thank you for your answer, it's not a problem with the fan, on my laptop it's a stock cooler, but on W7 it has no problem, on my workstation I have a water cooler, no problem with W7, only linux distros burn through the cpu's, I think it has something to do with kernel configuration, not sure yet, my time doesn't allow much investigation now, but I think I'm on to something, but this will require me to do a few kernel builds... unless of course there's a way of enabling all options on build and then later disable stuff, thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a dual-boot Windows/Linux box and I had the same problem with the fan control. It's because my box configuration is unique and my ACPI bios is broken. Like me your only option is to write a fan control driver yourself. Mostly you cannot get support from your supplier and because it's Linux it doesn't make it easier. Luckily it's not a very complicated task when you know a bit of programming and because linux expose the embedded controler to a device file when with windows it's protected by the OS and you need a special library or you need to buy a certificate from MS and write a kernel driver. You only need to find the register to control the fan for example you can monitor the ec and step through different cpu load. First off I recommend to install RW tool for windows to check the ec. Or you can write a dump tool in Linux.

Comment: thank you, can you give a bit more details on how I can solve this issue? I experience it on a custom build and on a dell laptop...

Comment: What do you want to know? I don't solve homework.

Comment: "...Like me your only option is to write a fan control driver yourself..." <- pointing me towards a starting point would help a lot!

Comment: @DorinDuminica: Install RW tool and look for the register to control the fan. I can only supply you with my driver if you want a tutorial I suggest you to use google. You can find my driver on my website and my website is in my signature.